# API call = undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-product-api

So I am using the Amazon product advertising API. I have it searching and rendering the results for the majority of searches, however it seems to crash if the API call results have nil values in some fields.

I have tried to overcome it by using a ternary operator, however this still doesn't seem to work, the API call with missing data components results in the following error message:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

**Below is the relevant code from my controller:**

Original Attempt:

```
@hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
    product = OpenStruct.new
    product.Title = item['ItemAttributes']['Title']
    product.image = item['MediumImage']['URL']
    product.ASIN = item['ASIN']
    product.URL = item['DetailPageURL']
    product.Feature = item['ItemAttributes']['Feature']
    product.Price = item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice']
    @products << product
end
```

Ternary Operator in Use:

```
@hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
    product = OpenStruct.new
    product.Title = item['ItemAttributes']['Title'] ? item['ItemAttributes']['Title'] : nil
    product.image = item['MediumImage']['URL'] ? item['MediumImage']['URL'] : nil
    product.ASIN = item['ASIN'] ? item['ASIN'] : nil
    product.URL = item['DetailPageURL'] ? item['DetailPageURL'] : nil
    product.Feature = item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] ? item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] : nil
    product.Price = item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'] ? item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'] : nil

    if product.Title || product.image || product.ASIN || product.URL || product.Feature || product.Price === nil
      @products << product
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use hash['key'].present? while testing in ternary operation.

So your code, instead of the following:

```
@hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
    product = OpenStruct.new
    product.Title = item['ItemAttributes']['Title'] ? item['ItemAttributes']['Title'] : nil
    product.image = item['MediumImage']['URL'] ? item['MediumImage']['URL'] : nil
    product.ASIN = item['ASIN'] ? item['ASIN'] : nil
    product.URL = item['DetailPageURL'] ? item['DetailPageURL'] : nil
    product.Feature = item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] ? item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] : nil
    product.Price = item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'] ? item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'] : nil

    if product.Title || product.image || product.ASIN || product.URL || product.Feature || product.Price === nil
      @products << product
    end
end
```

should be as follows:

```
@hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
    product = OpenStruct.new
    product.Title = item['ItemAttributes']['Title'].present? ? item['ItemAttributes']['Title'] : nil
    product.image = item['MediumImage']['URL'].present? ? item['MediumImage']['URL'] : nil
    product.ASIN = item['ASIN'].present? ? item['ASIN'] : nil
    product.URL = item['DetailPageURL'].present? ? item['DetailPageURL'] : nil
    product.Feature = item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'].present? ? item['ItemAttributes']['Feature'] : nil
    product.Price = item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'].present? ? item['OfferSummary']['LowestNewPrice']['FormattedPrice'] : nil

    if product.Title || product.image || product.ASIN || product.URL || product.Feature || product.Price === nil
      @products << product
    end
end
```

But I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here:

```
if product.Title || product.image || product.ASIN || product.URL || product.Feature || product.Price === nil
  @products << product
end
```

Are you trying to add the `product` to the `@products` array, only if one of  `Title`, `image`, `ASIN`, `URL`, `Feature`, or `Price` are present ? If it is, then your code doesn't work. You should update it to the following:

```
if product.Title.present? || product.image.present? || product.ASIN.present? || product.URL.present? || product.Feature.present? || product.Price.present?
  @products << product
end
```

**UPDATE:**
As it is possible that any or all the attributes of the `item` are optional, you could use the following approach, instead of ternary operation:

```
@hashed_products['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
  product = OpenStruct.new
  product.Title = item.try(:[], 'ItemAttributes').try(:[], 'Title')
  product.image = item.try(:[], 'MediumImage').try(:[], 'URL')
  product.ASIN = item.try(:[], 'ASIN')
  product.URL = item.try(:[], 'DetailPageURL')
  product.Feature = item.try(:[], 'ItemAttributes').try(:[], 'Feature')
  product.Price = item.try(:[], 'OfferSummary').try(:[], 'LowestNewPrice').try(:[], 'FormattedPrice')

  if product.Title.present? || product.image.present? || product.ASIN.present? || product.URL.present? || product.Feature.present? || product.Price.present?
    @products << product
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Dharam, I am not sure whether a ternary operator is in fact the best approach. I tried your solution, adding .present? however it is still crashing on XML data sets where some of the criteria are NIL. Any other approaches in mind?

Comment: Provide the stacktrace to see where it is failing.

Comment: The error message shows that it fails on product.image. So I assume that not all items have images, or medium sized images.

Comment: If I can ensure that the nil values in product.image are handled correctly, then I can do away with the if ... || ....... || @products << product end